# Error when updating GAE application - missing appengine-web.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, google-app-engine

Good morning,

I'm creating GAE apllication with some endpoints. I was uploading my app many times and everything was OK, but something happened (i think it's my pom.xml) and now i can call

```
 maven install
```

without errors, but when i call

```
maven appengine:update
```

console shows FileNotFoundException because appengine-web.xml is missing.

This is my stack trace:

```
    com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate D:\Workspace\myProject\v0.6\myProject\target\myProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.<init>(Application.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.readApplication(Application.java:322)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readWar(AppCfg.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.readApplication(AppCfg.java:274)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:212)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:124)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:248)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\myProject\v0.6\myProject\target\myProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
    ... 31 more
```

I've copied "build" section in my pom.xml from here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/pom.xml

Of course I'm not suprised, because in my "target" directory i have only "class" directory, but I don't know why "WEB-INF" in this directory is not generated.

--EDIT--

Of course I've created appengine-web.xml in my WEB-INF directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my fault. I had

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

instead of

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

in my pom.xml, so project was not generated properly.